# Scala: getting rid of type argument in a function

Tags: scala

Suppose I have a function defined in the following way:

```
def fun[T](somevar: SomeType[T]) = { 
   // some action 
}
```

Is there a way to git rid of type parameter `[T]` and just use it as

```
def fun(somevar: SomeType[T]) = { 
   // some action 
}
```

I mean, the type information should already be available inside `someVar`, no? Why not use them somehow?

Comment: Would this be just to avoid typing the extra characters when you define the function? Or are you hoping to gain something else?

Comment: Well, as a programmer it is not an issue; the issue is that we are creating a Scala-based language for users (who are not Scala programmers) to use it; that's why we are trying to make it as simple as possible, for non-Scala users.

Comment: What I meant was, are there any other situations that you're hoping to improve with this change, other than the way the function name is written when defined? Perhaps some code when it's called, or something else?

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of your question is unclear.

The users of your function (the client code) don't need to worry about the type parameter.  They can just call `fun(myvar)`.

If the type `T` is immaterial to the body of `fun()` then it can be dropped: `SomeType[_]`

But if `T` is meaningful to the workings of the function then the compiler has to be told that it is a type parameter.  Just seeing this, `SomeType[T]`, the compiler can't infer that `T` is now a type parameter.  It will, instead, look for a definition of `T` outside of `fun()` and, not finding it, will throw an error.

Answer (score 2):

This would be problematic because what you're removing was never actually redundant. When the function is defined as `def fun[T](...)`, `T` is defined as a new type variable. Otherwise, it refers to a type or type variable defined somewhere else. You seem to think that

```
def fun(somevar: SomeType[T]) { ... }
```

should mean that `T` is a new type variable. Is that always the case, though? Not in this code:

```
trait T { ... }
def fun(somevar: SomeType[T]) { ... }
```

So where do we go from there? Define new type variables whenever a type name is referred to that hasn't been defined before? That would turn the following compile-time errors truly weird. (Or worse, sometimes allow them to compile?)

```
def fun(somevar: SomeType[Integr]) { ... }

class C[Thing] {
  def g(x: List[Think]) = ...
}
```

For the compile-time type-checking philosophy of Scala, that way lies madness.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want `T` to be a specific type, no, there is not. The method signature wouldn't be valid without it. What `somevar` knows is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. Compiler needs to know what is type `T`. If you don't care about `SomeType` type parameter, you can use this form:

```
def fun(somevar: SomeType[_]) = { 
   // some action 
}
```